# python3.2 - ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found

Tags: ubuntu, python, compile, make

We have a legacy application and it **needs Python version 3.2 to work**. For this reason we **compile and install** Python version 3.2.

We were able to successfully compile and install version 3.2 Python on **Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS**, but we started to have problems using the **Python "hashlib" library** as can be seen in the excerpt below...

```
root@sinj:/usr/local/src/lbginst# /usr/local/lb/py32/bin/python3.2 -c "import hashlib;m=hashlib.md5();print(m.hexdigest())"
ERROR:root:code for hash md5 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/python3.2/hashlib.py", line 141, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/python3.2/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type md5
ERROR:root:code for hash sha1 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/python3.2/hashlib.py", line 141, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/python3.2/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha1
ERROR:root:code for hash sha224 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/python3.2/hashlib.py", line 141, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/python3.2/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha224
ERROR:root:code for hash sha256 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/python3.2/hashlib.py", line 141, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/python3.2/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha256
ERROR:root:code for hash sha384 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/python3.2/hashlib.py", line 141, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/python3.2/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha384
ERROR:root:code for hash sha512 was not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/python3.2/hashlib.py", line 141, in <module>
    globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
  File "/usr/local/lb/py32/lib/python3.2/hashlib.py", line 91, in __get_builtin_constructor
    raise ValueError('unsupported hash type %s' % name)
ValueError: unsupported hash type sha512
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'md5'
```

**QUESTION:** How can we solve the problem presented?

**NOTE I:** After consulting dozens of sources on the internet, we started to suspect something related to the *libssl.so* *libcrypto.so* binaries.
**NOTE II:** Information on how we can diagnose what is happening is also very welcome!

**Thanks! =D**

---

**UPDATE:** Another symptom is the occurrence of this message during building process (`make`, `make install`)...

```
Failed to build these modules:
_hashlib           _ssl
```

Comment: why not use something like virtualenv instead of compiling?

Comment: How can I create a virtualenv for Python 3.2 if I don't have Python 3.2? Thanks! =D

Comment: you don't need python 3.2, you need any version of python and you use that to bootstrap python 3.2

Comment: And how I do it? Any tips? =D

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html

Comment: I appreciate your effort @SathyajithBhat , but this is not possible without having the desired version of Python installed. =D [Refs.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1534210/use-different-python-version-with-virtualenv , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293436/how-to-specify-python-version-used-to-create-virtual-environment?rq=1 ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems pointed out occurs because python version 3.2 is not compatible with openssl version 1.1 which is the standard version (`apt-get`) used by Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

The solution is compile and install (`make`, `make install`) version 1.0 of openssl and configure the compilation process using the variables "CFLAGS" and "LDFLAGS" so that it uses openssl version 1.0.

```
# NOTE: Download, compile and install openssl. By Questor
cd /usr/local/src
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/old/1.0.2/openssl-1.0.2k.tar.gz
tar -zxvf openssl-1.0.2k.tar.gz
cd ./openssl-1.0.2k
./config -fPIC shared
make && make install
cd ..
rm -rf ./openssl-1.0.2k

# NOTE: Download, compile and install Python 3.2. By Questor
cd /usr/local/src
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.2.2/Python-3.2.2.tgz
tar -zxvf Python-3.2.2.tgz
cd ./Python-3.2.2

eval "./configure --with-threads --enable-shared CFLAGS='-I/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl/ -I/usr/local/ssl/include/' LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/lib/ -L/usr/local/ssl/lib/ -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/lib/ -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/ssl/lib/'"
make && make install
cd ..
rm -rf ./Python-3.2.2

# NOTE: Test python3.2 using "_hashlib" and "_ssl" resources. By Questor
/usr/local/bin/python3.2 -c "import hashlib;m=hashlib.md5();print(m.hexdigest())"
```

**Done! Thanks! =D**

[**Refs.:** https://chowyi.com/%E6%BA%90%E7%A0%81%E7%BC%96%E8%AF%91%E5%AE%89%E8%A3%85Python3%E5%8F%8A%E9%97%AE%E9%A2%98%E8%A7%A3%E5%86%B3/ ,
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/66782/how-to-install-openssl-1-0-2-on-raspberry-pi3/66788?newreg=89c76bb5b1f542f88a63268243455e75 ,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1904990/what-is-the-difference-between-ld-library-path-and-l-at-link-time/1905144#1905144 ,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409092/coredump-when-compiling-python-with-a-custom-openssl-version/22409394#22409394 ,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937337/building-python-with-ssl-support-in-non-standard-location/5939170#5939170 ,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537271/compile-openssl-with-the-shared-option/23513969#23513969 ,
https://www.hpc.dtu.dk/?page_id=1180 ,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24026737/3223785 ,
https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/security/ssl/determining-the-openssl-version ,
https://superuser.com/a/1618761/195840 ,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46476640/3223785 ]

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you're using OpenSSL 1.1 and an old version of Python that doesn't support that version of OpenSSL.  Python 3.2 was released in 2011 and OpenSSL 1.1.0 was released in 2016.

Since OpenSSL 1.0 is no longer security supported, you'll need to upgrade the version of Python you're using to a suitable version.  If you can't wait and you plan to upgrade in the next three months, you could also use an Ubuntu 16.04 container, which contains OpenSSL 1.0 which is supported by Ubuntu until April.  However, Python 3.2 likely has unpatched vulnerabilities as well.

Comment: One possible solution is install Python 3.2 using a compiled version of openssl as seen here https://stackoverflow.com/a/5939170/3223785 . Additionally we would have to adjust via "./configure" and the parameters/variables "CPPFLAGS" "LDFLAGS" before starting the Python 3.2 make process. Thanks! =D

Comment: Yes, although if you used a version of OpenSSL you compiled yourself, it would lack security patches and you'd have a security problem, whereas if you used Ubuntu's, you wouldn't.  I specifically didn't suggest you do a thing which would lead you to have an insecure OpenSSL because it's not appropriate to advise someone to run insecure software connected to the Internet, as it puts other users and systems at risk.

Comment: I truly appreciate your concern, but this compiled version of openssl will only be used by Pytho 3.2, unlike the version installed on the system via "apt-get". Other than that, we have taken many other steps regarding the security of our infrastructure so that our risk will be "low". There is no way to adapt the legacy application that will use this feature, so this is the solution we have for today. Thanks! =D